# MySQL Query to retrieve last entry in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables (Version Minor to MySql 8) in a simple chat app

Chat

| id_chat | chat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My first chat |
| 2 | My Second Chat |

And Chat_Message

| id_chat_message | id_chat | message | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | How | 03/Mar/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | Are you | 04/Mar/2021 |
| 3 | 2 | This | 05/Mar/2021 |
| 4 | 2 | Is other | 06/Mar/2021 |

How can I make a Query if I want to retrieve the last message for every chat?

The resultset should be

| id_chat | chat_name | last_message | last_message_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My first chat | Are you | 04/Mar/2021 |
| 2 | My Second Chat | Is other | 06/Mar/2021 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.id_chat, c.chat_name, cm.message, cm.date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id_chat ORDER BY cm.date DESC) rn
    FROM Chat c
    INNER JOIN Chat_Message cm ON cm.id_chat = c.id_chat
)

SELECT id_chat, chat_name, message, date AS last_message_date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can join to a subquery which finds the latest chat message from the second table.

```sql
SELECT c.id_chat, c.chat_name, cm.message, cm.date AS last_message_date
FROM Chat c
INNER JOIN Chat_Message cm
    ON cm.id_chat = c.id_chat
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_chat, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM Chat_Message
    GROUP BY id_chat
) t
    ON t.id_chat = cm.id_chat AND t.max_date = cm.date;
```

Comment: Thanks, is an old server so MySQL 8+ is not supported

Comment: @cbeltrangomez Thanks for the curve ball, I have updated my answer with a version which should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I came with this, but I'm not 100% sure it works in all cases:

```
SELECT hc.id_chat, hc.chat_name, hcm.message as last_message, hcm.date as last_message_date from chat hc inner join (SELECT a.* 
FROM chat_message a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_chat, MAX(date) date
    FROM chat_message
    GROUP BY id_chat
) b ON a.id_chat = b.id_chat AND a.date = b.date) hcm on hc.id_chat = hcm.id_chat group by hcm.id_chat;
```

Some inspiration came from [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: Nope, this is no good. And indicates that your using a version of MySQL prior to 5.7, which is really a bit out of date. :-(